# tSQLt There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR in Private_RunTest

Tags: sql-server, tsqlt

Whenever I use ExpectException I receive the following error: (There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.{Private_RunTest,140})

It appears that tSQLt is attempting a ROLLBACK after the fact that MSSQL has already performed the ROLLBACK due to the RAISERROR.
I wrapped the following SELECT and SET statement in Private_RunTest with the following IF statement and it appeared to resolve the problem.

```
IF ISNULL(@ExpectException,0) <> 1 
  BEGIN
    SELECT @Msg = COALESCE(@Msg, '') + ' (There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> ' + 
                  COALESCE(ERROR_MESSAGE(), '') + '{' + 
                  COALESCE(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '') + ',' + 
                  COALESCE(CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR), '') + '})';
    SET @Result = 'Error';
  END
```

Is this truly a bug and/or an appropriate fix?

Comment: Can you provide an example test case and code under test? Some errors, when thrown, create a situation where the transaction cannot be rolled back and no further writes can be made. When that happens, tSQLt has a problem because it cannot write a record to the test case log. However, each situation is a little different, so seeing your particular code could help.

Answer (score 5):

**You are probably not using TRY/CATCH blocks in your tsqlt test.**

The error message "*There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.*" can be reproduced as follows:

1) Create a Trigger that throws an error and rolls back as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTable_IUDTR] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

  BEGIN TRY
      RAISERROR('MyError', 16, 1)
  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH
      THROW;
  END CATCH

END
GO
```

2) Create a tsqlt test to check the error message returned:

```
CREATE PROC [ut_MyTable_IUDTR].[test that the error is returned]
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @ErrorMsg VARCHAR(50)

  EXEC tsqlt.FakeTable @TableName = 'MyTable'
  EXEC tsqlt.ApplyTrigger 'MyTable', 'MyTable_IUDTR'

  INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
          ( FirstName, LastName )
  VALUES  ( N'John',N'Smith')

  SET @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()

  EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsString @Expected = 'MyError', @Actual = @ErrorMsg

END
GO
```

3) Run the test:

```
EXEC [tSQLt].Run 'ut_MyTable_IUDTR.test that the error is returned'
```

4) You get the following Error:

```
    There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.
```

**THE FIX:**

**Change the tsqlt test to include TRY/CATCH blocks as follows:**

```
ALTER PROC [ut_MyTable_IUDTR].[test that the error is returned]
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @ErrorMsg VARCHAR(50)

  EXEC tsqlt.FakeTable @TableName = 'MyTable'
  EXEC tsqlt.ApplyTrigger 'MyTable', 'MyTable_IUDTR'

  BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
              ( FirstName, LastName )
      VALUES  ( N'John',N'Smith')
  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH
      SET @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
  END CATCH

  EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsString @Expected = 'MyError', @Actual = @ErrorMsg

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be using `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in your tsqlt test

```
CREATE PROC [testClass].[test foo]
AS
BEGIN
  SET XACT_ABORT ON
  EXEC tsqlt.AssertEquals @Expected = 1, @Actual = 0
END
```

Don't do this.

You'll get a message like this

`[testClass].[test foo] failed: (Error) Expected: <1> but was: <0> (There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.{Private_RunTest,160})`